# Zend framework save instead of insert update

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I want to use save method to save form data. but when i call save on object its gives following error. It works fine if I call insert method on object.
Fatal error: Call to undefined method

Application_Model_Content::save() in /var/www/html/ZendTecAdmin/application/controllers/AdminController.php on line 44

Following is my controller action code

```
$content  = new Application_Model_Content();
          if($this->_request->getParams('id')){
            $id =  $this->_request->getParams('id');  
            $row = $content->find($id)->toArray();   
            if($row){
            $form->populate($row[0]);
            }
           }

    if ($this->_request->getPost('Publish')) {
                $formData = $this->_request->getPost();           
                if ($form->isValid($formData)) { //If form data is valid  
                    unset($formData['Publish']);                
                    $content->save($formData);
                   //$content->insert($formData); //it works fine
                }
            }
```

Following is my model

```
<?php
class Application_Model_Content extends Zend_Db_Table
{
   protected $_name = "content";

}
```

Please help me to get it resolve.

Comment: There is no inbuilt method `save` exists in Zend. If you want, you need to create one check this for [reference](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.quickstart.create-model.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can get Row object and use save() on it:

```
$select = $content->select()->where('id = ?',$id);
$row = $content->fetchRow($select);
$row->name = 'John'
$row->birthdate = 1980-11-04;
$row->save();
```

To extend Row Class you can add `protected $_rowClass = 'Application_Model_Row_User';` to your Model and then you create `class Application_Model_Row_User extends Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract`.
Now you can add your own methods to this class like this :

```
public function dateToAge(){
    return (int)floor( (strtotime(date('Y-m-d')) - strtotime($this->birthdate)) / 31556926);
}
```

and later:

```
$select = $content->select()->where('id = ?',$id);
$row = $content->fetchRow($select);
$name = $row->name
$age = $row->dateToAge();
```

You can read more here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.table.row.html

Comment: which one is best to use as my below answer or yours?

Comment: Both solutions work, so you can pick what you like. When using my solution you can extend Row class and add more methods, which may be handy in bigger projects.

Comment: can you explore this :  extend Row class and add more methods

Answer (score 0):

It works fine if write code in model content as below

```
<?php

class Application_Model_Content extends Zend_Db_Table {

    protected $_name = "content";

    function save($data) {

        if (null === ($id = $data['id'])) {
            unset($data['id']);
            $this->insert($data);
        } else {
            $this->update($data, array('id = ?' => $id));
        }
    }

}
```

Is there any other standard way to do this?